# Running DinD or similar setup in k8s 1.24+ for unit tests during CI flow

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, containerd

Recently, we switched from Jenkins CI to GitLab-CI on K8s 1.24 with containerd. The Java applications we have contains unit tests / integration tests which would spin up some containers (for the likes of DBs and whatnot) temporarily. But once we started running this on GitLab, we realized K8s doesn't really support this flow as we do have some dependency inside the code like the usage of DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock to bind and to make docker API calls.

Has anyone else faced similar issues? Should I rewrite the test classes to leverage k8s Java client instead?